# MSI installation : cancel is not working

Tags: windows-installer

How exactly CANCEL button works in default installer UI?

If i click CANCEL button, some times i can able to see "do you want cancel setup" dialog box with yes or no options.

But some cases, this popup won't show up and installation continues.

I am seeing this problem, if i click CANCEL button at the end of first phase only. status message is "Coping new files".

"Coping new files" is deferred action. How come this message is showing in first phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's actually running the "Copying new files" action, or is it an action after that which doesn't post any progress updates? If it's a custom action, be careful that it does one of two things:

- Never calls MsiProcessMessage (or equivalent)
- Pays attention to the return codes of MsiProcessMessage and handles cancel appropriately

If the action never calls MsiProcessMessage, then Windows Installer will handle cancel for the action, but cannot cancel it in the middle of the action. If the action calls MsiProcessMessage (with certain values for `eMessageType`), then Windows Installer assumes that the action will process the cancel, and the action must return `ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT` or Windows Installer gets confused.

Comment: Almost all custom actions , before starting actual task, calling MsiProcessMessage to set status. Return type not handled properly.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly CANCEL button works in default installer UI? They are using multiple threads like BackgroundWorker in WindowsForms .NET. One thread for the UI and one for the  installation, if you click cancel(UI), it will try to stop the other thread(installation) AT A CERTAIN POINT IN TIME.

Comment: Am i missing something?  This issues only comes , if i click on cancel button at the end of first phase, where status message shows on ui is "Coping new files".

Answer (score 0):

The execute sequence of an MSI installation process runs in two phases:

1. First all actions which should be executed are written in a temporary installation script. This is immediate and it always shows the cancel popup.
2. The second phase runs that script and actually performs the installation. It runs as deferred. Depending on when exactly you press cancel, the popup may or may not be shown.

For example, the installation can no longer be canceled when commit actions start executing.

Comment: this issue comes in first phase. If i click on cancel button in second phase, i am getting cancel popup. But Only problem at the end of first phase.  One important note is, if i click on cancel button directly at 2nd phase, i can see popup. But if i click on first phase  end, i could not see...... and immediately  if i try again at 2nd phase, i cold not see cancel popup (install skipping further cancel button clicks).